# CSS media query iPhone max-width

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to target small screens (smartphones both in portrait and landscape orientation) with media queries.

For example the iPhone 6 has a resolution of 667 x 375, in logical pixels.

This media query targets it well (in portrait mode):

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 667px) {...}
```

Now if I want to target the same device, but in landscape mode, I thought I could do this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 667px) and (orientation: landscape) {...}
```

But that doesn't work. If I bump `max-width` to `668px` it does work.

Why doesn't the first one work?

EDIT: here is my viewport meta tag from `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Can you show me your meta viewport tag, please?.

Comment: @Alex I added the meta tag to my post

Answer (score 3):

**Working 100% all iPhones.**

```css
    /*============================================================================== 
    iPhone 4 and 4S || 320 x 480 || Default, Portrait and Landscape
================================================================================ */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) 
and (max-width: 480px){
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) 
and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) 
and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

/*============================================================================== 
iPhone 5, 5S, 5C and 5SE || 320 x 568 || Default, Portrait and Landscape
================================================================================ */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) 
and (max-width: 568px){
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) 
and (max-width: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) 
and (max-width: 568px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

/*============================================================================== 
iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 || 375 x 667 || Default, Portrait and Landscape
================================================================================ */
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) 
and (max-width: 667px){ 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) 
and (max-width: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) 
and (max-width: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

/*============================================================================== 
iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ || 414 x 736 || Default, Portrait and Landscape
================================================================================ */
@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) 
and (max-width: 736px){ 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) 
and (max-width: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) 
and (max-width: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

/*============================================================================== 
iPhone X || 375 x 812 || Default, Portrait and Landscape
================================================================================ */
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) 
and (max-width: 812px){ 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) 
and (max-width: 812px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) 
and (max-width: 812px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    .test-class{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}
}
```

Comment: A very simple, yet effective solution