# CSS to target phones only

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to use CSS to lock orientation on phones only but can't seem to get the code to work. I'm assuming it's because of the widths so I left them as ?.

```
/* SHOW MESSAGE ON LANDSCAPE ON PHONE */
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-device-width : ????) and (max-device-width : ????) { 
  #screen-lock { display:block; }
  #screen-display { display:none; }
}
 
/* (B) SHOW THE SCREEN ON TABLETS AND LAPTOPS */
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) and (min-device-width : ????) and (max-device-width : ????) {
  #screen-lock { display:none; }
  #screen-display { display:block; }
}
```

Comment: You can't target a _generic_ phone, as there is no _generic_ phone. You can only target screen widths, this answer includes some iPhone screen widths https://stackoverflow.com/a/59208280/3795691

Comment: Thanks @MattiaRighetti this answer put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the "all-in-one" answer I was looking for after checking out @Mattia's answer.

```
<div id="screen-lock">Please rotate me back to portrait</div>
<div id="screen-display">...</div>
```

and CSS code

```
/*============================================================================== 
Show lock screen on all small devices < 1000px width if put into landscape
================================================================================ */
@media only screen 
and (max-width: 1000px){ 
    #screen-lock { display: none; } #screen-display { display: block; }
}

@media only screen
and (max-width: 1000px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    #screen-lock { display: none; }  #screen-display { display: block; }
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width: 1000px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
     #screen-lock { display: block; } #screen-display { display: none; }
}


/*============================================================================== 
Disregard lock screen on devices > 1000px width
================================================================================ */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px ) 
{ 
    #screen-lock { display: none; } #screen-display { display: block; }
}
```

tested in responsive design mode (FireFox & Chrome) and this works on all devices smaller than an iPad. Any suggestions on improvement are always appreciated.